# C# Where are these assembly references coming from?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, assemblies

I have a `.csproj` where under references it lists Entity Framework and several SQLite assemblies. I want to remove them but they keep coming back. There is no `nuget.config` in the project. And this project does not reference SQLite. The reference part of the `.csproj` file makes not references to them:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PdfSharp-gdi, Version=1.50.5147.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\Packages\PDFsharp-gdi.1.50.5147\lib\net20\PdfSharp-gdi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PdfSharp.Charting-gdi, Version=1.50.5147.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\Packages\PDFsharp-gdi.1.50.5147\lib\net20\PdfSharp.Charting-gdi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="LocalLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\localpath\bin\LocalLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But within VS2019, Entity Framework is listed in the references along with SQLite assemblies. Where is it finding there references and how do I get rid of them?

[image: View within VS2019]

Comment: you use pdfsharp, it needs some resources to do its job

Comment: Looks like you're using an _old-style_ `*.csproj` file - can't you update to _SDK-style_ with `<PackageReference>` support?

Comment: In old-style projects, the NuGet references are defined in `packages.config`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config

Comment: My mistake. It's VS2019.

Comment: The nuget files are empty.